# Route in keystone.js for numerical value

Tags: node.js, express, keystonejs

I am redoing a wordpress blog in keystone.js and need to setup archives.  I need to replace 2012 with some sort of generic number detection to show the archive page.  Not the greatest solution but will work for this project.  I would just prefix the url with /archives/ but the blog is established as /year/month in the url.

```
    // Views
app.get('/', routes.views.blog);
app.get('/category/:category?', routes.views.blog);
app.get('/:post', routes.views.post);
 app.get('/2012/:month', routes.views.blog);
app.get('/pages/gallery', routes.views.gallery);
  app.all('/pages/about', routes.views.about);
app.all('/pages/contact', routes.views.contact);
```

Comment: so ideally something like app.get('/:anynumber/:month', routes.views.blog);

Answer (score 0):

I created blog archives for keystonejs.

https://github.com/cmillsLA/keystone-archives